# Number of rows returned by a SQL query changes at each execution

Tags: count, return, row, rows, teradata

I'm executing a complex query with views, tables and multiple subqueries, but everytime I execute the SQL code in Teradata, i get a new number of rows returned. The number  of rows returned is never the same and seems quite random .

Have you got any idea of what could be causing this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a RANDOM, SAMPLE or ROW_NUMBER  or any other OLAP function with an ORDER BY? If it's not uniquely ordered it might return different results for each run, causing differences for following joins...

Comment: Yes there is. And deleting the row_number function seems to get rid of the error, but I really need it. I'm going to keep looking and tell you if I find something

Comment: You need to either add more columns to the ORDER BY until it's unique or switch to RANK/DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER